# Why does the integral of -h[y] = - (integral of h[y]) for an indefinite integral but not for a definite integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Why is it that

```
Simplify[-Integrate[h[y],y]==Integrate[-h[y],y]]
```

evaluates to `True`

but

```
Simplify[-Integrate[h[y],{y,-A,A}]==Integrate[-h[y],{y,-A,A}]]
```

evaluates to

```
Integrate[-h[y], {y, -A, A}] + Integrate[h[y], {y, -A, A}] == 0
```

I have also tried FullSimplify and adding assumptions that A and h are both real to no avail.  Why is it that Mathematica seems to think that adding limits of integration introduces conditions  under which the equality may not hold? What would those conditions be?

This is Mathematica for Windows version 13.0.  I have not yet downloaded 13.1.

Comment: Perhaps the case where you cross a branch cut maybe the reason. In the first case a continuous integral is assumed, whereas in the second case the possibility of different branches are considered.

Comment: @danielhuber I see your point. I answered the question using an example.  Thanks for pointing that out. Are there cases where the definite integral converges but the equality does not hold? I would think not, at least over real numbers.

Comment: Note that `Simplify` does not operate on either `Integrate`.  It is the behavior of `Integrate` to factor out constants in indefinite integral but not in definite ones. I can’t recall any definition of the definite integral in which the constant multiple rule did not apply. (If one objects that when neither side exists, the equation is nonsense, then why not complain about the first case, since there exist nowhere-integrable functions?). There are Q&A on site about manipulating `Integrate` in the way the OP seeks.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2.  You said "There are Q&A on site about manipulating ``Integrate``" in the way I was seeking. Can you please point me to where this is discussed?

Comment: Sorry, I was on a phone. [Searching for `linearExpand`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=linearExpand) finds some of my answers that do algebra with `Integrate` (or `Sum`). You could also search for `linearCombine`.  There may be others. I'm not sure if any of those answers will do exactly what you want, but except for the few things `Integrate` does automatically, you usually have to do your own expression rewriting as I did in the answers in the search.

Answer (score 1):

@DanielHuber provided a remark that seems to answer the question. When Mathematica is doing an indefinite integral, it is providing an antiderivative, for which the equality is true.  For a definite integral, the integral may not converge.  For example, let $h(y)=\cot(y)$. Then $\int{\cot(y)dy}=\log(\sin y))$, and it is true that $-\int{h(y) dy} = \int{-h(y) dy}$. On the other hand, $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{\cot(y) dy}$ does not converge, and we cannot say that $-\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{h(y) dy}=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}{-h(y) dy}$.

Comment: Should `-Integrate[h[y], y] == -Integrate[h[y], y]` be `True`, `False`, or unevaluated because the integral might diverge? Note the two sides are literally identical, which is different than the question (not a typo).  Suppose two expressions $A$, $B$ are equal whenever both are defined, can we say $A=B$. For example, $\cos\theta\tan\theta = \sin\theta$, even though the two sides are different for $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: Or, should ``1/x == 1/x`` be ``True``, ``False``, or unevaluated, because $x$ might be zero? I understand your point. I have, by the way, reported the issue to Wolfram Support. I will report back on what they say.